# Joining columns based on number of fields

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I have a large workflow that gets tripped up by uncharacterized chromosomes - a process produces a count matrix that has *n* fields for canonical chromosomes, and for lines with uncharacterized chromosomes, the fields are *n + 1* and *n + 2*. This is a headache for using `read.table()` downstream.

My approach is to first identify what *n* is, and use this to isolate the *n + 1* and *n + 2* lines containing these uncharacterized chromosomes:

```sh
awk -v nf="$canon" 'NF!=nf{print}{}' matrix.txt | head
```

```
chr22   KI270733v1  random  123189  123362  +   6   4   8   0   0   10
chrUn   GL000220v1  105951  106963  -   0   0   0   0   10  0
```

The goal is for these lines to match the number of fields *n* by joining the 1st and 2nd columns where *n + 1* and the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns where *n + 2* to produce:

```
chrUn-GL000220v1    105951  106963  -   0   0   0   0   10  0
chr22-KI270733v1-random 123189  123362  +   6   4   8   0   0   10
```

#### Attempt

I could subset the matrix and split it into 3 files, one for *NF==n, NF==n+1 & NF==n+2* and join the columns:

```sh
awk -v n="$canon" 'NF==n{print}{}' matrix.txt | head

chr1    15534236    15536814    -   0   10  0   0   0   3
```

(^ no action needed)

```sh
awk -v n="$canon" 'NF==n+1{print}{}' matrix.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1"-"$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' | head

chrUn-GL000220v1    105992  107309  -   0   0   0   0   0   4
```

and

```sh
awk -v n="$canon" 'NF==n+2{print}{}' matrix.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1"-"$2"-"$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12}' | head

chr22-KI270733v1-random 123189  123362  +   6   4   8   0   0   10
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not dynamic - I have to specify the range of columns. The workflow could contain any number of columns after the first four detailing Chr, Start, Stop, Strand.

---

Hopefully I have defined the problem well, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -v n=13 '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF - n + 1; ++i) { $1 = $1"-"$i; $i=""; } } 1'
```

Accumulate into `$1` and clean `$i=""` the rest.

You could also move values to the left `if (NF != n) for (i = 2; i < NF; ++i) $i=$(i+(NF-n))` values and set `NF=n`.

Comment: Super, just had to tweak the whitespaces at the end:

`awk -v n=10 '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF - n + 1; ++i) { $1 = $1"-"$i; $i=""; } } 1' matrix.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1'`

Cheers Kamil